# How to find code for crash

Tags: debugging, memory

I have some 64-bit code that runs in release mode on a server. There's no Visual studio on the server, only on my dev-machine. The program has been written by many authors now (me latest), and some code in it I'm still not familiar with, and its quite big.

The program crashes now and then with a nullpointer. **The instruction at 0xwhatever (latest 0x40066c19) referenced memory at 0x00000000 - click on OK to terminate the program.** I have all the source and PDB files for the EXE, but when i run it and attach the process, the memory 0x40066c19 is completely out of range. There is only ?? in that area. How do you use the info about "the instruction at ..." ?

The disassembly window displays something like (example) - but as you see there are simply too far from 00000001403CB888 to 0x40066c19

```
   if (LastKickIdle > GetTickCount()) 
00000001403CB882  call        qword ptr [__imp_GetTickCount (0140688310h)]  
00000001403CB888  cmp         dword ptr [LastKickIdle (0140888DF8h)],eax  
00000001403CB88E  ja          CMainDlg::OnKickIdle+281h (01403CBAB1h)  
        return 1;
    LastKickIdle = GetTickCount() + 500;
00000001403CB894  mov         qword ptr [__formal],rbx  
00000001403CB89C  call        qword ptr [__imp_GetTickCount (0140688310h)]  
00000001403CB8A2  add         eax,1F4h  
00000001403CB8A7  mov         dword ptr [LastKickIdle (0140888DF8h)],eax
```

Comment: ASLR? To be hacky, The program can try writing the address of the crashing function at a file when it runs - considering that the absolute address may be different across different runs but their relative address difference is constant for each compilation. Also maybe you can try address sanitizer? I am not very familiar with the ASLR on Windows, hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar situations at work.  I created a `log` class that takes a string arg and writes it to a file with some other useful info.  I make entries at the beginning of methods or at places that I think something may be or may later be problematic.   With this, I have at least been able to narrow down my search for problems.
Hope this helps.